# custom object detection model breaks because of ParseFromString and StringIntLabelMap (python v3.5 w/ tensorflow v1.8)

Tags: python, tensorflow

This seems to be a problem that is unique to me because I have found 0 results on the web for it.

**First Error:**
[image: First Error]

**Second Error:**
[image: Second Error]

The command that I'm trying to run from my *object_detection* folder is this:

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

Here is my train.py (this should be the default since I have made no modifications to it): https://hastebin.com/gizaqutuje.py

> EDIT: I am starting to think this problem arises from my protobuf installation. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling different versions of protobuf using pip3, but that did not change the output at all.

I don't really know if there is anymore information that I should give that is relevant to this problem, but if I am leaving something out please let me know!

Comment: Maybe you can share the link from which you took the code, or post the code here?

Comment: @unholy_me I am only running the train.py file. I included a link to my train.py file in case you think that something might be wrong in the main post.